# ¿Cómo puedo modificar un background-image desde Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito cambiar el valor background-imagen de una etiqueta IMG:

```
<img style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 1px; background-position: -43.0385px -342px; width: 312px; height: 378px; float: left; cursor: default; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url("https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/885830-1.jpg&w=1080&h=720&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99"); top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" src="mifondo.jpg">
```

¿Cómo podria modificar yo background-image que está dentro de style y style está dentro de la etiqueta IMG con jquery o javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer referencia a la imagen desde Javascript y, desde allí, acceder a la propiedad `backgroundImage` para poder cambiarsela. Supongamos que le pones el id `imagen`.

Sería así:

### Mediante Javascript

```
var imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
imagen.style.backgroundImage = "url('tuUrl')";
```

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta que `backgroundImage` va junto para poder modificarlo desde Javascript.

### Mediante JQuery

```
$('#imagen').css("background-image", "url(tuUrl)");
```

Comment: Esta es la etiqueta bro, lo hice pero no funcionó.  <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 1px; background-position: -340.731px -24.6607px; width: 312px; height: 378px; float: left; cursor: default; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/885830-1.jpg&amp;w=1080&amp;h=720&amp;far=1&amp;bg=ffffff&amp;q=99&quot;); top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>

Comment: @RubxnMC ¿Cómo ejecutas el Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: javascript, pero ya funcionó bro.. ¡GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1):

Con jQuery deberías utilizar el método `css`:

```
$imagenObj.css('background-image', 'url("http://....")');
```

Con javaScript lo harías a través de la propiedad `style`:

```
imagenObj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://....")';
```

Ten en cuenta que seguramente tengas que cambiar también la propiedad `backgroundPosition`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#cambiar').click(function(){
      $('#imagen').css('background-image', 'url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/despicableme/images/0/06/Daveault2.png/revision/latest?cb=20130911160410")');
      $('#imagen').css('background-position', '0 0');
  });
});

document.getElementById('cambiarjs').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(){
    var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
    imagen.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41sEBuTV6KL._SL500_AC_SS350_.jpg")';
    imagen.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 1px; background-position: -43.0385px -342px; width: 312px; height: 378px; float: left; cursor: default; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/885830-1.jpg&w=1080&h=720&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99'); top: 0px; left: 0px;display:inline-block" src="mifondo.jpg" id="imagen" />

<button id="cambiar">Cambiar jQuery</button>
<button id="cambiarjs">Cambiar javascript</button>
```