# ¿Cómo puedo recoger el color de fondo de un div, o cualquier elemento ,con JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

El caso es que quiero recoger el color de fondo de un div para mostrarlo y no se como recogerlo.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo modificar un background-image desde Javascript/JQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123189/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-modificar-un-background-image-desde-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Podes probar con

```
$('div.class').css('background-color')
```

Abrazo!

Comment: Y para recogerlo de varios div que tienen clases diferentes??

Comment: escribe los nombres de las clases y cada clase separalas con comas @StewieGriffin

Answer (score 2):

Espero que te sirva esta respuesta, no entendí muy bien cual es le caso especifico en que quieres usar esto, pero mas o menos para explicar algunos puntos genere este ejemplo sencillo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para explicarte a grandes rasgos con `jquery` puedes:

- Obtener el color de fondo de un elemento html `.css('background-color');`:

  ```
  $("div").css('background-color');//De un elemento html, div, button, input, etc.
  $(".clase").css('background-color');//por clase(todos los elementos de esa clase indicando con . que se refiere a una clase)
  $("#id").css('background-color');//por id(el elemento con el id indicado despues de #)
  ```
- Asignar un color algún elemento html `.css('background-color',color);`:

  ```
  $("div").css('background-color',color);
  $(".clase").css('background-color',color);
  $("#id").css('background-color',color);
  ```

```js
$('#GenerarColores').click(function(){
  GenerarColores();
  $('#Resultados').html('');
});

$('#ObtenerColores').click(function(){
  ObtenerColores();
});

function GenerarColores(){
  $.each($('.color'),function(i,v){
    var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    /*
    console.log(color);    
    console.log(v);
    */
    $(v).css('background-color',color);
  });
}

function ObtenerColores(){
 var lis = '';
  $.each($('.color'),function(i,v){
    var text = $(v).text();
    var color = $(v).css('background-color');
    /*
    console.log(text);
    console.log(color);
    */
    lis += '<li>' + text + ': <label style="color:' + color + '">' + color  + '</label></li>';
  });
  //console.log(lis);
  var resultados = '<ul>' + lis + '</ul>'
  $('#Resultados').html('');
  $('#Resultados').append(resultados);
}
```

```css
.color{ 
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='GenerarColores'>Generar Colores</button>
<br/><br/>
<div class='Colores'>
  <div class='color'>Div 1</div>
  <div class='color'>Div 2</div>
  <div class='color'>Div 3</div>  
  <div class='color'>Div 4</div>
  <div class='color'>Div 5</div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button id='ObtenerColores'>Obtener Colores</button>
<div id='Resultados'>
</div>
```