# ¿Como Cambiar Un Background Image Desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Amig@s quisiera saber como hago para modificar el Background Image desde JavaScript, aquí les dejo mi código y le explico un poco mas.

HTML

```
<div class="contenedor-imagen">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.contenedor-imagen {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid 2px #026aff;
    background-image: url(img/1200x1200.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var catProduct = $(this).attr('src');
document.querySelector('.contenedor-imagen').style.backgroundImage = catProduct;
```

en el codigo javascript tengo una variable llamada **catProduct** que es una url como por ejemplo https://dominio.com/img/foto.png y quisiera remplazar la url que esta en background-image por la que tengo en esa variable pero el problema esta es que como le coloco el **url()** que lleva el estilo?

Esto quisiera hacer:

background-image: **url(** "aqui la url que tengo en la variable catProduct" **)**;

Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: Siempre es conveniente ver si ya se ha hecho una pregunta similar y ver sus respuestas. En éste caso, ya hay uno y con respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/123195/155688

Comment: si amig@ funciona pero como hago yo si la url de mi imagen la tengo en una variable? y no anotándola directamente en el JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Intentaste hacer esto: `document.querySelector('.contenedor-imagen').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + catProduct + ")"`?